# How to capture return value from tkinter buttons without using global variable?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to capture return value from a tkinter button using the following code:

```
self.Init = tk.Button(self.FRAME, text ="Initialize", command = lambda: self.main_df = self.initialize())
```

The return value is a pandas dataframe.

This is throwing an error (invalid syntax)

How can I fix this code or achieve the same thing by other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
self.Init = tk.Button(self.FRAME, text ="Initialize", command = lambda: self.initialize(self.main_df))
```

And instead of return
`self.main_df = return_data_frame`

Comment: Thank you! So from what I understand, self variables can be accessed across functions. Is that right?

Comment: self is easy way to access class variables and by puting self as input for functions they are aveliable in any function of that class